# DDSmoothMenu bad CSS layout

Tags: css

I use the [DDSSmoothMenu](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm) tree to build my categories tree. But, I don't know how to fix that problem:

[image]

as You can see, there are line-broken categories title. If someone used that menu, know how to force it to display the all titles in one line ? (like that two titles on the left)

Comment: may be it because of the width of that sub menu become less...Try to increase the width..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anish's commented, explicitly setting the width got the job done. Thanks !